# Non-Ascii characters not supported by .net?

Tags: .net, ascii, naming

When I added a class with non-Ascii caharacters in the class name, it removed the non-Ascii from class name and when added directly to class it complains of non-Ascii characters.

Are Non-ASCII characters not supported in class name and variable name?

Comment: In the interest of code reuse, I'd stick to names that use ASCII characters, as all keyboards can type them.

Comment: yes but here I am creating class for the user at runtime of the name supplied by the user, the question is that, is non-ASCII allowed by .net and can I allow the user to give non-ASCII names.

Comment: If your users are programmers, they are used to ASCII restrictions. If your users are not programmers, you should not be creating classnames from their naive input.

Comment: @Vinay I expect this is for some type of run time loading.  Perhaps you need a different design for simplicity, if you want to handle non-ascii characters.

Comment: I'm somewhat saddened by the fact that everyone seems to just say "Use ASCII". Yes, I too would prefer that everything is written in English, but let's face it, not all code is. If the choice is between some romanization or ASCII-fication and the name in the native alphabet, I'd much prefer the latter - it's more readable to the people who'll be working with it, and it's generally easier to look up in a dictionary if you MUST work with the code without knowing the language in question.

Comment: @Michael: you are on an English based site :)

Comment: @Matthew: If you speak English as your native language, and you prefer to code in English, it shouldn't come as any surprise that there will be people in China who prefer to code in Chinese, and there will be people in Spain who prefer to code in Spanish. If you have to use foreign-language identifiers, Unicode identifiers are a perfect fit, since they're easily available (many languages support them these days - it's not just .NET languages) and they're more readable than the alternative of using unaccented letters or some ASCII-fication/romanizaiton scheme.

Comment: @Michael, very true... but it doesn't stop me from thinking how much more fun we could start to see with third party libraries and interop.

Answer (score 4):

Read section 9.4.2 from the [ECMA Standard for C#](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to save the file with an encoding that supports the characters that you want to have in your class name:

- Click File -> Save as
- Click the little arrow by the save button, and select "Save with encoding..."

However, it feels like begging for trouble to have class names that requires an extended encoding (but it's only a feeling I get; don't have any experience with it, really).

Comment: @Fredrik, the file created say ÃŸÃ¶Ã¤Ã¼Ã³.cs is fine but in class name it is public class wieredName instead of public class ÃŸÃ¶Ã¤Ã¼Ã³.

Comment: @Vinay: ÃŸÃ¶Ã¤Ã¼Ã³ looks a LOT like mangled Unicode. I would expect that's UTF-16(LE), and that the real name should be 쎟쎶쎤쎼쎳 - that would be Korean, and no, I can't tell you what that means. (It could be UTF-8, but that expands to ßöäüó, which I *know* is nonsensical).

Answer (score 0):

This compiles and runs for me

```
public class 嗨世界
{
    public 嗨世界() {}

    public void Run()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, Unicode world.");
        System.Console.WriteLine("type= {0}", this.GetType().Name.ToString());
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            new 嗨世界()
                .Run();
        }
        catch (System.Exception exc1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", exc1.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

ps: I have no idea what those characters mean.

Comment: Did you check to see what the second `.WriteLine(...)` returns?

Comment: the type name.  But I can't see it in my cmd.exe console, which is not unicode. If I Replace that line with a MessageBox, `            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String.Format("type= {0}", this.GetType().Name.ToString()));`, then I see the type name as expected.

Comment: @Matthew: You can't go by what that second WriteLine shows in the console. The console settings on your computer are unlikely to be prepared for CJK, because the font used won't have the character and there won't be a font fallback defined, so it can't show the character. You'd get a more accurate view by putting it in a file or in some WinForms control.

Comment: @Michael: Okay, how about ildasm?

Comment: While this would work... I would highly not recomend it.  You are just asking for trouble later.

Comment: @Matthew: ildasm doesn't write it correctly if you ask for console output, unless you've changed the codepage to 65001 (UTF-8) and pipe it to a file (I assume file output will work if you pass one of the /UTF8 or /UNICODE switches). The GUI has no problems, and it shouldn't: Unicode identifiers are even allowed in CLS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx

Comment: The UI in ILdasm doesn't play very nice either.  I didn't say this didn't work, I just said I wouldn't do it. (Okay, I said I wouldn't recommend it.)

Comment: @Matthew: The UI doesn't exactly render it nicely (the font it uses isn't ideal), but it's the right characters that are being shown. On pre-Vista, however, the fonts aren't installed by default - I believe you have to enable complex script rendering in the Regional and Language Options applet.

Comment: I am probably just biased for how long I have been constrained to ASCII.  It would work, just seems freaky to me.